# How do I plot 2D map like this image in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

[image: Plot that I want to achieve using the data that I post here]

I am trying to create a plot like the image using the [data attached here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byk7SKspaHtUTGFILVpwZGpJdkE/view?usp=sharing), however when I try to plot the grid data I am having a memory error.

I can only plot the the file using scatter option from matplotlib like my following example:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

dffold = pd.read_csv('foldmap.toc', delimiter='\t',encoding='latin1',usecols=['Inline','Crossline','X','Y','Fold'])
x1 = np.array(dffold.X)
y1 = np.array(dffold.Y)
zf = np.array(dffold.Fold)
xi = np.linspace(min(x1), max(x1))
yi = np.linspace(min(y1), max(y1))
A, B = np.meshgrid(xi, yi, copy=False)
zi = griddata((x1, y1), zf , (xi, yi), method='nearest')
plt.scatter(x1,y1,zf)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Here is the link of the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byk7SKspaHtUTGFILVpwZGpJdkE/view?usp=sharing and the image is posted on the top of the question.

Comment: on what line do you get the memory error?

Comment: could you use `pcolormesh` rather than `scatter`?

Comment: if I change the plt.scatter to plt.colormesh using the same variables I get the following error: :\WinPython27101\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.pyc in _pcolorargs(funcname, *args, **kw)
   4993         if len(args) == 3:
   4994             X, Y, C = [np.asanyarray(a) for a in args]
-> 4995             numRows, numCols = C.shape
   4996         else:
   4997             raise TypeError(

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Zachi, it only works with the scatter option, if a I change the function then the script gives me the error that I mentioned before.